# Quantum Physics - decorrelate 2 particles initially entangled

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement

I am studying the entanglement in quantum physics, especially the [Aspect's experience](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exp%C3%A9rience_d%27Aspect) where 2 photons initially correlated keep this correlation through the measure of their polarity. The Wikipedia article is only available in French, but there is [an article in English written by Alain Aspect](https://physics.aps.org/articles/v8/123) here that describes the experiments.

I am wondering if there is a way, from an experimental or theoretical point of view, to decorrelate 2 entangled particles ?

Is there any experience which has be performed in this goal to remove the entanglement ?

Comment: Entanglement is destroyed by [quantum decoherence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_decoherence). Any interaction with a system that has many degrees of freedom will do it.

Comment: Is "just throw away any particles you have, and the entanglement is gone" a valid answer?  If not, why not?

Comment: -@John Rennie if I have well understood, a system of 2 entagled particles can't be never considered as an isolated system, can it ? however, for the moment, we don't know if there is a distance limit for entanglement, beyond which entanglement would have disappeared.